# Expansion of $e^x$ - correct form

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I have come across in a textbook to an expansion of e to the x in the following form:
$$
1+ \frac1x + \frac1{x^2} + \frac1{x^3} + \ldots
$$
Is the above correct or is it a typo?

I am familiar with this type of expansion for e to the x:
$$
1+ \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots
$$

Are they both correct? If yes, how is the first one above arrived at? I could not find it online anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No.  There is a unique expansion of $e^x$.  The second one you list is it.

Comment: The first one is a geometric series and sums to $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{x}{x-1}$ when $|x|>1.$

Comment: The second provide an upper bound for $e^x$ for $x<1$.  It is not equal to $e^x$ unless $x=0$.

Comment: The second series is exactly equal to $e^x$ for all real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the first series has a ratio of terms of $1/x$, thus, assuming $|1/x| < 1$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{x^k}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1/x)^k
 = \frac{1}{1-(1/x)}
 = \frac{x}{x-1}
 = 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} \ne e^x.
$$

Comment: ok. So my math is not so great. but i guess you are saying that the textbook with that form of expansion for e^x is actually wrong then?

Comment: @adriano yes, that expansion is incorrect

Comment: thank you for confirming